# Python scrape specific tag without class name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm developing a python script to scrape data from a specific site.
I'm using Beautiful Soap as python module.
The interesting data into HTML page are into this structure:

```
<tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
  <tr  style="">
   <td>
      <a href="www.server.com/art/crag">Name<a>
   </td>
   <td class="nowrap"></td>
   <td class="hidden-xs"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

into tag tbody there are more tr tag and I would like take to each only first tag a of tag td

I have tried in this way:

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find(id='tabella_falist')
b = a.find("tbody")
link = [p.attrs['href'] for p in b.select("a")]
```

but in this way the script take all href into all td tag. How can take only first?

Thanks

Comment: What output you expect ? I'm not sure about what you are trying to extract

Comment: Each <td> tag have a <a> tag with href but i would take only the href value of first <td> tag that not have a class name

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'your_url'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.a)
```

`soup.a` will return the first `a` tag on the page.

Comment: Yes but i would retrieve the first a tag into td tag. the td tag is into tr tag and there are more tr tag into tbody tag

Comment: In this way i take the first tag a, but i want the first tag a of a tr list

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
html = '''<html><body><tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
  <tr  style="">
   <td>
      <a href="www.server.com/art/crag">GOOD ONE<a>
      <a href="www.server.com/art/crag">NOT GOOD ONE<a>
   </td>
   <td class="nowrap">
      <a href="#">GOOD ONE</a>
   </td>
   <td class="hidden-xs"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></body></html>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for td in soup.select('td'):
    a = td.find('a')
    if a is not None:
        print a.attrs['href']
```